# Reading a delimited text file with php

Tags: php

I have a program that generates text files, and I want to read that file and extract a specific data from it with.
The script needs to search the text file keys, and return the value into a variable .

My text file looks this:

```
"KEY1" "value to be returned" timestamp
"KEY2" "value to be returned" timestamp
```

I've tried with explode, etc, but it not works.
Thank you in advance,
Andy.

Comment: This is a terrible way to store your data IMO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`fgetscsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

```
$data = fgetcsv ( $fh, NULL, ' ');
```

This will read your file like a CSV, but will use the space as a delimiter.

`explode()` is too blunt a tool for this, as you're using quotes to give spaces their literal meaning.